# Display iPhoto library name in application title bar

Tags: photos.app, macos

I am working with multiple iPhoto libraries and it isn't always clear which one is currently open when launching iPhoto. **How can I display the name of the iPhoto library in the application title bar so that I always know which library I have open?**

Doing a bit of searching, it seems that iPhoto Library Manager will do this if iPhoto is launched from that application.

As an alternative, is there a way to force iPhoto to prompt to select a library every time it launches?

Answer (score 1):

Holding <kbd>ALT/Option</kbd> when you start the app provides a dialogue on startup to choose your iPhoto Library.  Someone may be able to suggest an AppleScript that replicates this on a click, so you can replace your iPhoto dock icon with a scripted alias instead.

Comment: I'm aware of this option, but the problem is when iPhoto is launched without this option it isn't necessarily clear which library you are working with as there is no prompt and no visual indication in the title bar.

Comment: The "Option" key is going to be your best bet unless you use iPhoto Library Manager.  Otherwise, you can hold the Command key down while clicking on the title at the top of the application window to show you the full path to the current library...